# Which loop more efficient/preferable - foreach or while loop

Tags: c#

A foreach inside a foreach loop:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var list2 = new List<int>() {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
foreach (var list1Value in list1)
{
    foreach (var list2Value in list2)
    {
        if (list1Value == list2Value)
            // do something
    }
}
```

Or an IEnumerable inside a foreach loop

```
var list1 = new List<int>() {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var list2 = new List<int>() {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}
var enumerator = (System.Collections.IEnumerator)list2.GetEnumerator();
foreach (var list1Value in list1)
{
    enumerator.Reset();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (list1Value == (int)enumerator.Current)
            // Do something
    }
}
```

I prefer the first for readability, but think the second more efficient. Note that the code is just an example, it's not indicative of the code I'm actually running.

Comment: It's a personal preference and thus I suspect this will get closed. I find the first more readable personally. No need to overcomplicate a solution.

Comment: What do you intend to do for "Do something"?

Comment: With foreach inside a foreach, does the compiler create a new enumerator for the second foreach on each iteration of the first foreach loop?

Comment: Actually, you'd save more by using for loops and having the outer loop start `i = 0` and the inner loop start at `j = i + 1` so you don't do redundant comparisons.

Comment: If you want to find out which of two things is faster, **write it both ways, run it both ways, and measure the performance**. Then you'll know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it doesn't matter if you choose to use a `foreach` or `while` loop because a `foreach` loop is actually broken into a `while` loop after it has been compiled to IL.

Take a look at this `foreach` loop:

```
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
 foreach (int e in enumerable)
 {

 }
```

After it has been compiled to IL it looks like this:

```
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
IEnumerator<int> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        int element = enumerator.Current;
        //here goes your action instructions
    }
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

I would always prefer the more readable code which definitly is the `foreach` loop.
For further information read this great article: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/01/internals-of-loops-while-for-and.html

Answer (score 3):

With ten items per list, nobody cares about ten allocations of the enumerator saved by the call of `Reset`. This is definitely a micro-optimization, even though the second approach does save you some allocations. I would definitely go for more readability of the first approach, or even add some LINQ, like this:

```
foreach (var list1Value in list1) {
    var tmp = list1Value;
    foreach (var list2Value in list2.Where(item => item == tmp)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want?

```
var list1 = new List<int>() {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var list2 = new List<int>() {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
foreach (var item in list1.Intersect(list2))
{
    // Do something
}
```